# Find common features of the group that make it different from another

Tags: r, intersection

I have two groups of patients (ill and healthy). Each patient has features with ranks like so:

```
healthy_patient1 <- data.frame(feature=c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), rank = c(0.001, 0.002, 0.002, 0.003, 0.05, 0.067))
healthy_patient2 <- data.frame(feature=c("a", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "q"), rank = c(0.001, 0.008, 0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.067, 1.2))
healthy_patient3 <- data.frame(feature=c("c", "d", "e", "g", "k", "l"), rank = c(0.003, 0.005, 0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.08))
healthy_patient4 <- data.frame(feature=c("b", "e", "g", "d", "k", "q", "o"), rank = c(0.001, 0.008, 0.01, 0.021, 0.054, 0.078, 1.1))

ill_patient1 <- data.frame(feature=c("c", "d", "e", "f", "o", "p", "q"), rank = c(0.002, 0.004, 0.005, 0.006, 0.02, 0.067, 0.09))
ill_patient2 <- data.frame(feature=c("e", "f", "o", "p", "r"), rank = c(0.001, 0.003, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03))
ill_patient3 <- data.frame(feature=c("c", "e", "o", "n", "k", "r"), rank = c(0.003, 0.005, 0.01, 0.03, 0.04, 0.08))
ill_patient4 <- data.frame(feature=c("b", "e", "o", "h", "n", "r", "s"), rank = c(0.002, 0.007, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.068, 1.1))
```

ranks show the specificity of the feature in a particular patient, the lower the rank, the more important is the feature.
I want to find common features among healthy patients that differ them from ill patients. And vice versa features that are common for ill patients that differ them from healthy patients.

Also, I need to know the common features' ranks sum

I tried this:

```
healthy_comm <- intersect(intersect(healthy_patient1$feature, healthy_patient2$feature),intersect(healthy_patient3$feature, healthy_patient4$feature))
ill_comm <- intersect(intersect(ill_patient1$feature, ill_patient2$feature),intersect(ill_patient3$feature, ill_patient4$feature))
setdiff(healthy_comm, ill_comm)

    healthy_comm 
[1] "d" "e"
    ill_comm 
1] "e" "o"
    setdiff(healthy_comm, ill_comm) 
[1] "d"
```

I can go back and find "d"'s rank sum in the original data, but in my real datasets, I have a lot more patients and features. So, maybe there is a more elegant and efficient solution to this problem

upd. The desired output in this case would be "d", sum_rank_healthy(d)=0.037, sum_rank_ill(d)=0.004

Comment: it seems like an interesting question.  can you please include the desired output for the sample records you have given here, whether calculated manually

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic idea how it could work:

1. Add name of dataframe as column to all your dataframes
2. then create dataframes `df_healthy` and `df_ill` with `bind_rows`
3. then apply `inner_join` by `feature` in this example (you could also use `rank`) with the output you can find common and different features.

```
ill_patient1$patient <- "ill_patient1"
ill_patient2$patient <- "ill_patient2"
ill_patient3$patient <- "ill_patient3"
ill_patient4$patient <- "ill_patient4"

healthy_patient1$patient <- "healthy_patient1"
healthy_patient2$patient <- "healthy_patient2"
healthy_patient3$patient <- "healthy_patient3"
healthy_patient4$patient <- "healthy_patient4"
 

df_healthy <- bind_rows(healthy_patient1, healthy_patient2, healthy_patient3, healthy_patient4)
df_ill <- bind_rows(ill_patient1, ill_patient2, ill_patient3, ill_patient4)


library(dplyr)
inner_join(df_ill, df_healthy, by = "feature")
```

**You may extent**

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(df_ill, df_healthy, by = "feature") %>% 
  mutate(common_rank = as.logical(rank.x == rank.y))
```

Output

```
   feature rank.x patient.x    rank.y patient.y        common_rank
   <chr>    <dbl> <chr>         <dbl> <chr>            <lgl>      
 1 c        0.002 ill_patient1  0.002 healthy_patient1 TRUE       
 2 c        0.002 ill_patient1  0.003 healthy_patient3 FALSE      
 3 d        0.004 ill_patient1  0.003 healthy_patient1 FALSE      
 4 d        0.004 ill_patient1  0.008 healthy_patient2 FALSE      
 5 d        0.004 ill_patient1  0.005 healthy_patient3 FALSE      
 6 d        0.004 ill_patient1  0.021 healthy_patient4 FALSE      
 7 e        0.005 ill_patient1  0.05  healthy_patient1 FALSE      
 8 e        0.005 ill_patient1  0.01  healthy_patient2 FALSE      
 9 e        0.005 ill_patient1  0.01  healthy_patient3 FALSE      
10 e        0.005 ill_patient1  0.008 healthy_patient4 FALSE      
# ... with 29 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `mget`

```
library(dplyr)
 df1 <-  mget(ls(pattern = 'ill_patient')) %>% bind_rows(.id = 'patient')
df2 <- mget(ls(pattern = 'healthy_patient')) %>% bind_rows(.id = 'patient')
inner_join(df1, df2, by = 'feature')
```